# Replace HealthAggregator for Spring Boot 2.6.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-actuator

I want to migrate old Spring project which is using this dependency:

```
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthAggregator
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.OrderedHealthAggregator
    ..........
    @Autowired
    private final HealthAggregator healthAggregator = new OrderedHealthAggregator();
```

This Class requires import of:

```
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.0.2.RELEASE'
```

I tried to use the latest version in version Spring Boot 2.6.4:

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.StatusAggregator;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.OrderedHealthAggregator;
```

But I can't find which class is replacing `OrderedHealthAggregator`

Do you know which class should be used in Spring Boot 2.6.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderedHealthAggregator` was replaced by [`SimpleStatusAggregator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.4/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/SimpleStatusAggregator.html).